# Java Check string has only certain words and characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to verify that a String only contains certain words and characters.

I'm going to receive a string, and need to check that it only contains the following:

- "("
- ")"
- " AND " Note the spaces
- " OR " Note the space
- any integer. If I can check that it's less than 10 at the same time, that would be a bonus, but I can do that separately if it complicates the code.

If there is any other character or word in the string, I need to reject it.

A valid string would be:
(1 OR ((2 AND 3) OR 4 AND 5))

I think a regex is the way to be going about this, but I can't work out how to build the regex to do this.

I know the regex patterns are:

- \(
- \)
- \sOR\s
- \sAND\s
- \d+

I've joined them together, so the pattern is:
"\sOR\s|\sAND\s|\d+|\(|\)"

This obviously works in that it will find any of the values, but won't reject the string if there are extra characters or strings in the string.

I don't have to use a regex, but as I'm learning about them, this would be an ideal example for some help.
I've been using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html to test different combinations, but have admitted defeat for now.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Note that regular expressions can (normally) only match regular languages. If you want the regex to check for matching paranethesis as well, then you've left "regular-language-country": regexes can't do that. In other word: you won't be able to recognize "(1 or (" as an illegal expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your constructed regex together with the [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method provided you escape all your `\` and allow repeated occurences with the `+` operator:

```
boolean happy = testString.matches("(\\sOR\\s|\\sAND\\s|\\d+|\\(|\\))+");
```

I'm not sure what you mean by `less than 10`, but if you mean that the number can be 0-9, you can just replace `\\d+` with `\\b\\d\\b`. If instead you mean 1-9 digits are allowed, you can use `\\b\\d{1,9}\\b`.

Comment: About the "less than 10", you must check that the digit is not followed by another digit replacing `\\d+` by `\\d(?!\\d)` (or `\\d\\b` or `\\b\\d`). No need to check the other side.

Comment: @Casimir: Yeah, I just realized. I think adding word boundaries (`\\b`) will take care of the problem in a clean way.

Comment: @Keppil Thanks for the reply. matches seems to work, so I'll test that some more. When I said less then 10, I should have said less than or equal to 10.
So 1 OR 10 is valid, but 1 OR 11 isn't. I don't think that's possible with a regex.

Comment: Actually, don't worry about the 1 to 10. I can cater for that elsewhere in my code. So this looks like the solution I'll be using. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take your acceptable characters and place them in a constant. Then take the String your testing and turn it into a character array and go through it character by character and see if it is in your constant. Blow up if not. Successful completion = good String.

I don't think there's a shorter way.